# how to make increase number animation work only on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my code for increasing number animation. [Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/1m25rdw1/)

Code:

```js
$('.Count').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  jQuery({
    Counter: 0
  }).animate({
    Counter: $this.text()
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(this.Counter.toFixed(1));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Count">7.4</span>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<span class="Count">3.7</span><br/>
<span class="Count">9.1</span><br/>
<span class="Count">5.6</span>
```

Now, how do i increase the number only on scroll? I tried to use  count::before, but it did not work. I am not professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this is what you want

```
countEach()
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    countEach()
})

function countEach() {
    $('.count').each(function() {
        if (showOnScreen(this) && $(this).attr('show') != 'false') {
            console.log($(this).text())
            console.log($(this).attr('show'))
            $(this).attr('show', 'false')
            numberAnimate(this)
        } else if (!showOnScreen(this)) {
            $(this).attr('show', 'true')
        }
    })
}

function showOnScreen(target) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(target).offset().top)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function numberAnimate(target) {
    var $this = $(target);
    jQuery({
        Counter: 0
    }).animate({
        Counter: $this.text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(this.Counter.toFixed(1));
        }
    });
}
```

[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1m25rdw1/7/)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts bro, but. This code  have 2 problems:

1.) The counter works only 1 time, I want it to work again, If their are more counters downside. 
2.) It work only on scroll. If the <span> is already on screen, on page load, it do not work. 

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1m25rdw1/6/

Comment: Hey I made some change, you can make changes you want base on this :p